# Dataset about variation in human body weight during the day

Tags: data-request, india, asia, north-america

I need a dataset that monitors the variation in human body weight at different parts of the day, preferably of Indian/South Asian population. I did an comprehensive research and pulled some relevant research papers.

The research paper [Day-to-day variations in body-weight of young women](http://tinify.net/scD) is pretty old. Do we have newer research that includes data taken at multiple times a day?

I know the [DHS has good datasets](https://www.dhsprogram.com/Data/) but I could not find the dataset I am looking for.

Preferably I want a dataset of people who were currently loosing weight.

Comment: *Idea:*  datasets from wrestlers or jockeys or other athletes who need accurate control of their weight for competition.